ошибка в Zenject - Unable to resolve 'A' while building object with type 'B'. Object graph:
Ошибка: ZenjectException: Unable to resolve 'PiesOfIngridient' while building object with type 'Ingredient'. Object graph:
Ingredient
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;

public sealed class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller // в SceneСontext
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Lavash _lavash;


    public override void InstallBindings()
    {

        this.Container
           .Bind<Lavash>()
           .FromInstance(this._lavash)
           .AsSingle();

    }
}


using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;

public sealed class IngridientInstaller : MonoInstaller // в GameObject Context
{

    [SerializeField]
    private PiesOfIngridient Ingr; // префаб ингредиента для спавна

    [SerializeField]
    private Ingredient basket;
    
 

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {

        this.Container
            .Bind<Ingredient>()
            .FromInstance(this.basket)
            .AsSingle();
           

        this.Container
          .Bind<PiesOfIngridient>()
          .FromNewComponentOnNewPrefab(this.Ingr)
          .AsSingle();

          

    }
}


public class Ingredient : MonoBehaviour
{

    private PiesOfIngridient ingr; // префаб ингридиента
    private Lavash lavash;
    
    [Inject]
    public void Construct(Lavash _lavash, PiesOfIngridient _ingr)
    {
        lavash = _lavash;
        ingr = _ingr;
    }


Оказалось что GameObject Context просто не видел мой класс из-за того что тот не являлся его дочериным объектом. Из-за этого не все зависимости перекидывались!
